# Selecting extra data from tables [Laravel]. passing parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, select, laravel-5

In Laravel, 
Actually, what I wanted to get was I've a function which fetches **4 cols** from  table

```
public function getData($id)
    {
        $user = $this->user->select(
            'users.name',
            'users.id',
            'users.email',
            'users.address as  address')
            ->where('users.id', $id)
            ->first();

        return $user;
    }
```

> I've 2 more columns. They are '**enabled, occupation**'. I want to fetch that two columns as well calling to the same function getData(). 
>   So How can I able to do that? Need Help.

Comment: does your query giving proper result? If so, why can't you give users.enabled and users.occupation in query while fetching?

Comment: Yes it does. I mean I've to call it from 2 different locations. One where I just want these four cols only and another where I want 4 cols + 2 cols data.

Comment: single table or two different table?

Comment: single table...

Comment: why cant's you fetch users.enabled and users.location and store in some variable for processing?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your requirement. Anyhow you will be having id of the user so you can fetch data of particular user.

```
public function getData($id)
    {

     $user = User::query()->select('name','id','email','address','enabled','occupation')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

     $enabled = $user['enabled'];
     $occupation = $user['occupation'];

     return $user;
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's not like my requirement. But I'll take that as **+ve** point. And thanks for helping. It was useful.